# Handling resonse with more than 500 MB - Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Im using apache camel for integration, Could you please help in handling response with more than 500 MB. I'm consuming SOAP service end point.

Using Apache camel 2.17 version, consuming https SOAP end point.

Currently im facing connection timeout exception, even I have increased my connection time out to 15 mins.

Answer (score 0):

If the response you get is fairly big. The client needs some time to receive the data.

There are a couple of timeout parameters:

**ConnectionTimeout**: Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the client will attempt to establish a connection before it times out. The default is 30000 (30 seconds). 0 specifies that the client will continue to attempt to open a connection indefinitely.

**ReceiveTimeout**: Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the client will wait for a response before it times out. The default is 60000. 0 specifies that the client will wait indefinitely.

In order to don't have connection timeouts you could use `0` or at least a bigger number. However, this may have consequences for your application.

Comment: Hi Nazeem, Thanks for your response, Yes I have already defined  Connection Timeout and Receive Timeout as same what have mentioned, In fact I have increased the timeout values, still im facing the same issue.